# SharePoint 2010 User Control save property

Tags: sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts

Is this possible to save property of user control in SharePoint 2010 like we do in WebPart?

Actually I need to add a control on MasterPage so that it present on every page to track what site user is visiting. Using webpart we can save the property but the webpart cannot be added on MasterPage.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can store your custom settings in several places in SharePoint and grab them in your control and use'em. have a look at this nice article [here](http://www.scolts.com/?p=65) to get an idea of where to store your settings.

Comment: You mean I can save some data in Property bag of User Control? How can I do that?

Comment: If you choose the Property Bag then you should save you control properties to the SPSite.Properites. User control properties will not do. For example your control might save a key value pair to the property bag with a key of your string smth like "mycontrol.masterpage" and a value containing all you required info.

Comment: Depending on your specific situation you should choose between SPFarm.Properties, SPWebApplication.Properties, SPWeb.Properties or SPSite.Properties